# Does "the care of A" mean that "someone looks after A" or "A looks after someone"?

Tags: american-english, british-english

> They shared the care of the children.

This is a straightforward sentence telling us that "they looked after the children".

> The study showed a deep fear among the elderly of being abandoned to
>   the care of strangers.

Why does this sentence mean that "Strangers look after the elderly",not "the elderly looks after strangers"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right: you have identified an ambiguity in English.

When a noun is formed from a verb, like "care", it is sometimes ambiguous whether an "of" complement is semantically the subject or the object of the verb.

Other examples:

> The experience of poverty  ("poverty" is the object of the verb "experience")
>
> The experience of people in the past ("people" is the subject of "experience")
>
> The choice of colours is soothing ("colours" is the object of "choose")
>
> The choice of the majority of visitors was not to take a tour ("the majority of visitors" is the subject of "choose").

In this case only real-world experience lets us conclude that "the children" is the object of "care", but "strangers" is the subject.

Answer (score -2):

You are not seeing the difference between "care" as a *noun*, and "care" as a *verb*.

- noun: care
  the provision of what is necessary for the health, welfare, maintenance, and protection of someone or something.
- verb: care
  look after and provide for the needs of.

> They shared the care of the children.

This is care as a *noun*. The parents look after their children and that provision is called "care".

> The study showed a deep fear among the elderly of being abandoned to the care of strangers.

This is care as a *verb* - the action of strangers looking after the elderly.

Comment: Why before a verb can use "the"?

Comment: No, this answer is wrong. "Care" is a noun in both cases.